# Where do images attached in enhanced note body get stored?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

Can anyone tell me when we add any image in notes, where it get stored? and From where I can access those images and download them?

[image: Here is the screenshot of the note with image]

Answer (score 0):

The links are embedded in the html of the Content.

Try `system.debug([SELECT Content FROM ContentNote][0].Content.toString());`

The html will contain the `<img>` tag with a source url.